# Automate the writing of complex elastic requests

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, filter, request, elastic-stack

I get a string from my user that represents an elastic request. There can be the following types of requests:

Single term: `TERM:MATCH_TERM` ;

Several terms separated by **AND**: `TERM:MATCH_TERM AND TERM:MATCH_TERM AND TERM:MATCH_TERM` ;

Several terms separated by **OR**: `TERM:MATCH_TERM OR TERM:MATCH_TERM OR TERM:MATCH_TERM` ;

Several terms separated by **AND** and **OR**: `TERM:MATCH_TERM AND TERM:MATCH_TERM OR TERM:MATCH_TERM AND TERM:MATCH_TERM OR TERM:MATCH_TERM AND TERM:MATCH_TERM` ;

The `OR` operator has priority over the `AND` operator

I parse this string next and get a list of my different terms.

I want to use this list now to build my elastic query. I know I will have to use the syntax for complex queries: `bool`. (I use the javascript client of elastic to make my request)

From what I understand, the `must` filter will allow me to do an **AND** and the `should` filter will allow me to do an **OR**.

In the case where we have: `TERM1:MATCH_TERM1 AND TERM2:MATCH_TERM2 OR TERM3:MATCH_TERM3 AND TERM4:MATCH_TERM4 OR TERM5:MATCH_TERM5 AND TERM6:MATCH_TERM6` ;

Would the correct syntax be something like this:

```
"query":{
    "bool":{ 
      "should":[
         "must":[
             {"terms":{"TERM1":"MATCH_TERM1"}}
         ] , 
         "must":[
             {"terms":{"TERM2":"MATCH_TERM2"}}
         ] , 
      ],
      "should":[
         "must":[
             {"terms":{"TERM3":"MATCH_TERM3"}}
         ] , 
         "must":[
             {"terms":{"TERM4":"MATCH_TERM4"}}
         ] , 
      ],
      "should":[
         "must":[
             {"terms":{"TERM5":"MATCH_TERM5"}}
         ] , 
         "must":[
             {"terms":{"TERM6":"MATCH_TERM6"}}
         ] , 
      ],
    }
  }
```

If there is any information missing to answer my question let me know and I will try to add it as soon as possible.

Thank you in advance if you take the time to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "TERM1": [
                    "MATCH_TERM1"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "terms": {
                  "TERM2": [
                    "MATCH_TERM2"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "TERM3": [
                    "MATCH_TERM3"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "terms": {
                  "TERM4": [
                    "MATCH_TERM4"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "TERM5": [
                    "MATCH_TERM5"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "terms": {
                  "TERM6": [
                    "MATCH_TERM6"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, it's exactly what I wanted. And do you know if inside the second "bool" you can put a `should`?

Comment: @vincent Yes, there is no limit to nested queries